# lodash - Move object to first place in array?

Tags: arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects, with type of `fruit`/`vegetable`:

For the one type `vegetable` I have, I want it to be the first item in the array, but I am not sure how to do so with lodash.

```
var items = [
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'apple'},
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'banana'},
    {'type': 'vegetable', 'name': 'brocolli'}, // how to make this first item
    {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'cantaloupe'}
];
```

Here is a fiddle with my attempt:
https://jsfiddle.net/zg6js8af/

How can I get type `vegetable` to be the first item in the array regardless of its current index?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using lodash [_.sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy). If the type is vegetable, it will be sorted first, otherwise second.

```js
let items = [
  {type: 'fruit', name: 'apple'},
  {type: 'fruit', name: 'banana'},
  {type: 'vegetable', name: 'brocolli'},
  {type: 'fruit', name: 'cantaloupe'},
];

let sortedItems = _.sortBy(items, ({type}) => type === 'vegetable' ? 0 : 1);

console.log(sortedItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here is another solution without using lodash.

```js
function sortBy(array, fn) {
  return array.map(v => [fn(v), v]).sort(([a], [b]) => a - b).map(v => v[1]);
}

let items = [
  {type: 'fruit', name: 'apple'},
  {type: 'fruit', name: 'banana'},
  {type: 'vegetable', name: 'brocolli'},
  {type: 'fruit', name: 'cantaloupe'},
];

let sortedItems = sortBy(items, ({type}) => type === 'vegetable' ? 0 : 1);

console.log(sortedItems);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use lodash when you do not need it (and can write functional code using a single `reduce`) ?

```js
var items = [
  {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'apple'},
  {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'banana'},
  {'type': 'vegetable', 'name': 'brocolli'},
  {'type': 'fruit', 'name': 'cantaloupe'}
];

var final = items.reduce(function(arr,v) {
  if (v.type === 'vegetable') return [v].concat(arr)
  arr.push(v)
  return arr
},[]);
alert(JSON.stringify(final));
```

Comment: Thank you for showing an alternative method, upvoted :) I am using lodash in many places already and prefer its clean syntax to be honest; even when the end goal is the same :)

Comment: why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: array.push, isn't a good solution in 2018, imo. better to use spread syntax, arr = [...arr, 'new item']

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with ordering by `type` in `desc` direction:

```
var res = _.orderBy(items, ['type'], ['desc']);
```

or using `partition`

```
var res = _.chain(items)
    .partition({type: 'vegetable'})
    .flatten()
    .value();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was trying to get it working based on the actual value `===` of `vegetable`, so it's flexible :)

Comment: Thanks again, but I went with the `_.sortBy` since it was a single method :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise solution in ES6 that uses the Array's `reduce` function:

```
const items = [
  { type: 'fruit', name: 'apple' },
  { type: 'fruit', name: 'banana' },
  { type: 'vegetable', name: 'brocolli' },
  { type: 'fruit', name: 'cantaloupe' }
]

const final = items.reduce(
  (accumulator, current) =>
    current.type === 'vegetable'
      ? [current, ...accumulator]
      : [...accumulator, current],
  []
)
console.log(final)
```